# Cant get xammp to send email through PHP

Tags: php, gmail, xampp

Having big problems trying to get my php script to send email. Using this script on my mac:

```
 <?php

require_once 'lib/swift_required.php';  
$image = file_get_contents("php://input");  
$attachment = Swift_Attachment::newInstance($image, 'submission.jpg', 'image/jpg'); 

$message = Swift_Message::newInstance()  
    /*Give the message a subject*/  
    ->setSubject('Your subject')  
    /*Set the from address with an associative array*/  
    ->setFrom(array('email'=>'Name'))  
    /*Set the to addresses with an associative array*/  
    ->setTo(array('email'))  
    /*Give it a body*/  
    ->setBody('Email'); 
    $message->attach($attachment);//<--When the attachment above is commented out, so is this  

    $transport = Swift_SendmailTransport::newInstance();  
    $mailer = Swift_Mailer::newInstance($transport);  
    $mailer->send($message); 

?>
```

email sends fine, attaches the image and is great. However this doesn't work on windows. I've read windows doesnt have a mail server so have spent that last few days fighting with hmailserver, mercury, mailsender etc. trying to get an email to send.
I get a weird error from swiftmailer:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Swift_TransportException' with message 'Process could not be started [The system cannot find the path specified. ]' in C:\xampp\htdocs\lib\classes\Swift\Transport\StreamBuffer.php:268 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\lib\classes\Swift\Transport\StreamBuffer.php(66): Swift_Transport_StreamBuffer->_establishProcessConnection() #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\lib\classes\Swift\Transport\AbstractSmtpTransport.php(101): Swift_Transport_StreamBuffer->initialize(Array) #2 C:\xampp\htdocs\lib\classes\Swift\Transport\SendmailTransport.php(61): Swift_Transport_AbstractSmtpTransport->start() #3 C:\xampp\htdocs\lib\classes\Swift\Mailer.php(74): Swift_Transport_SendmailTransport->start() #4 C:\xampp\htdocs\Mail.php(20): Swift_Mailer->send(Object(Swift_Message)) #5 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\lib\classes\Swift\Transport\StreamBuffer.php on line 268
```

So I tried a basic mail() script and that doesnt work. I've used stunnel and that doesnt seem to work. I'm completely lost. Some direction, a tutorial, anything you can offer please guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Linux systems, mail is sent from PHP via the mail() function which uses Sendmail. Whenever I use Swiftmailer on windows, I use SMTP, which gmail allows.

http://www.swiftmailer.org/wikidocs/v3/smtpauth